# Batch script find and replace

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, find, findstr

I have a batch script that is using psping and outputting the output to a file as follows

```
psping -l 8192 -i 1 -n 5 -w 0 localhost >> %outfile%
```

Then, I am just looking for the lines that have a "Reply" as follows:

```
findstr /N "Reply" %outfile%
```

As you know, the lines obtained are in the following format:

```
Reply from <IP>: 8.59ms
Reply from <IP>: 9.18ms
Reply from <IP>: 8.82ms
Reply from <IP>: 9.40ms
Reply from <IP>: 8.81ms
```

I then have this subroutine that replaces the spaces with commas

```
findstr "Reply" %pingfile% >> %textfile%
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%textfile%) do @call :processeachline %%a
endlocal
goto :eof
:processeachline
setlocal
set data=%*
echo %data: =,%
endlocal
goto:eof
```

The above results in the following output.

```
Reply,from,<IP>:,8.81ms
```

But I need it in the following format.

```
Reply from,<IP>,8.81,ms
```

The entire code is as follows
    @echo off
    @set local
    echo The date is %DATE%

```
@set tag=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%
set pingfile=psping%tag%.txt

echo file name:  %pingfile%

if exist %pingfile% (
echo deleting existing ping file...
del %pingfile%
)

set "tempfile=tempOut.txt"
set "newfile=csvOutput%tag%.txt"
if exist %tempfile% (
echo deleting existing temp output file...
del %tempfile%
)


echo Ping started at %DATE% %TIME% >> %pingfile%

REM Ping 5 times with an interval of 10 seconds between each with 0 warmup
psping -i 1 -n 5 -w 0 cnn.com >> %pingfile%



REM When done, parse the file and get only the necessary lines for the CSV
findstr "Reply" %pingfile% >> %tempfile%

REM parse the temp file and replace all spaces with commas and write to the csv
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%tempfile%) do @call :processeachline %%a

goto :eof
:processeachline
set data=%*
echo %data: =,% >> %newfile%

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr ms %newfile%') do @call :processeachlines "%%a"

goto :eof
:processeachlines
set data=%~1

echo %data:ms=,ms%

@endlocal
```

How do I go about doing this (ideally without opening the %textfile%)? I have to use the standard windows tools and cannot install any GNU packages.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Will all the lines be the same? You could just use `:` as a delimiter, and hardcode `Reply from,localhost,` in the output? (only the delay would be a filled by the `for` loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

findstr "Reply" %pingfile% >> %textfile%
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (%textfile%) do (
   set rest=%%b
   echo %%a !rest: =,!
)
```

Comment: in changing the code to what you have above, the result is: "Reply !rest: =, !" . Am i missing something? Also, the "localhost" will vary based on the IPs that I am pinging.

Answer (score 0):

This is your routine from above, with some changes in the separated block:

```
findstr "Reply" %pingfile% >> %textfile%
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%textfile%) do @call :processeachline %%a
endlocal
goto :eof
:processeachline
setlocal
set data=%*

set data=%data: =,%
set data=%data::=,%
set data=%data:ms=,ms%
set data=%data:Reply,from=Reply from%

echo %data%
endlocal
goto:eof
```